# Password update from a Spring Boot/Angular application

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I have a REST application written using Spring Boot that serves an Angular 2+ client. I need to implement a feature that allows user to change their password from their user dashboard. Being new to Angular, I need some guidance on where to implement this feature; whether it's from the front-end or back-end.

I have created some controller that maps to the password change from my spring boot back end, However I don't know how to proceed and link it to my angular application.

My only code snippet so far:

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/sysusers/changePassword")
public ResponseEntity<?> updatePassword(@RequestBody User user) throws 
Exception {
    userService.updatePassword(user.getUsername(), 
user.getPassword());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new 
CustomResponse(CustomResponse.APIV, 201, true, "Password updated 
successfully"),
            HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I expect a user to be able to update their password from the Angular based front-end which will have the password change forms and utilize functionality from the back-end. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: you need create a service in angular that use HttpClient to post request to Spring API

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this code at back end in the Spring controller and use this api at the angular end to change the password.